# VBA click check box

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to click a checkbox.  Nothing that I have researched has worked. Unfortunately the website is restricted so I wont be able to share the URL. So far I have been able to navigate to the website and then click a button that opens a table.  Once the table is open, I am unable to click the checkbox inside.  The goal is to click the checkbox with an ID of "Nuts", but I have no success in scraping or clicking anything in the table. I am relatively new with VBA.  I am not sure why the table is causing issues. I have tried the following and much more:

```
ie.document.getElementByID("Nuts").Click
ie.document.ALL.("Nuts").Click



table class= “PaddingTable2” style= “boarder-spacing: 1ox; width: 100%;”
<tbody>
<tr>…</tr>
<tr>…</tr>
<tr>
            <td>Apple:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Banana" type="text" value="100.000000" maxlength="11" id="Cherry" 
class="Date" style="width:155px;">
                <span data-val-controltovalidate="Elderberry" data-val-errormessage="FIG" id="grape" 
data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="honeydew" data-val-validationexpression="indago" 
style="visibility:hidden;">*
                </span>
             </td>
             <td> Jackfruit 
             </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Kiwi" type="text" maxlength="4" id="Lemon" class="Mango" 
style="width:155px;">
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input id="Nuts" type="checkbox" name="orange"><label for="pear">quinces</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
<tr>…</tr>
<tr>…</tr>
<tr>…</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so which?

Comment: Is the table inside an iFrame?

Comment: yes, it appears to be within an iFrame.

Comment: going to try this. ie.document.querySelector("[name='PopUpRadWindow']").contentDocument.querySelector("span[Class=aspNetDisabled]").Click